# How to get user picture using Asana API?

Tags: api, asana

I am trying to display user picture using Asana API, nut the /users/id service just return id, mail, name, workspaces. How can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana)

The API does not currently provide access to the user profile photo. It is something we are considering adding in the future, but I can't provide any specifics on the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

Until the API provides access to the photo, a useful workaround that we've been using is to get the user's email address out of Asana and then try to pull a picture from Gravatar. Obviously it requires the users to have registered at Gravatar, and they might have different pictures than what it is in Asana...  but it's good enough for many situations.

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana, too)

We recently added the ability to fetch (but not change) the user's photo. Check out the [updated documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/users) (specifically the "photo" attribute of the user model is what you're looking for).