# Access User Photo via Asana API

Tags: asana

I've done some research on this and was wondering if there is any way to access the user's photo via the Asana API?

The user photo I am referring to is the one that the user chooses in their profile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565482/how-to-get-user-picture-using-asana-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently added the ability to fetch (but not change) the user's photo. Check out the [updated documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#users) (specifically the "photo" attribute of the user model is what you're looking for).